# Multiselect input data should be inserted into database

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

i want according my plan

1. a form only have one multiselect item
2. can be cloned using jquery (.clone)
3. here must be a problem because same name of multiselect. (can be change using jquery).
4. all cloned forms data should be inserted into database accordingly new rows.

**view**

```
echo $this->Form->input('Book.category.', array(
                                                            'class'=>'js_cetegory',
                                                            'multiple' => 'multiple',
                                                            'type' => 'select',
                                                            'label' => 'Category',
                                                            'options'=>$categories,
                                                            'empty'=>'Select Category'
                                                            )
                                            );
```

name change code of multiselect input when clone is called

```
var len = $("#parent").length;
$(".top:first").clone().find(".js_cetegory").attr("name", "data[Book][cetegory]["+len+"][]").end().appendTo('#parent');
```

my $this->data is making this array code

```
[category] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 7
                )

            [1] => 
        )

    [cetegory] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 7
                    [2] => 8
                )

        )
```

instead of

```
[category] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 7
                )

             [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 7
                    [2] => 8
                )
        )
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: problem is when i inserting data into database.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Cake` is generating the field with `name` - `data[Book][cetegory][0]`, `data[Book][cetegory][1]` ...

It should be -

```
echo $this->Form->input('Book.category.0.', array(
```

But when cloning the names are changed to `data[Book][cetegory][1][]`

The name of the field sholud be -

```
$(".top:first").clone().find(".js_cetegory").attr("name", "data[Book][cetegory][][]").end().appendTo('#parent');
```

Comment: but when i clone my form then name of multiselect input remain same and when i submit form then two same name multiselect input will provide the last multiselect input data not both data. thats why i change the name of every upcoming multiselect inputs.

Comment: there are multiple multiselects?

Comment: yes obvious when i clone of particular DIV in a form there should be a duplicate of previous.

Comment: try this but when i clone element it generate -> `data[Book][cetegory][][]` :(

Comment: have added in my question